# How to return properly in a Solidity function?

Tags: return, arguments, solidity, declaration

I'm a total beginner with solidity, I've searched on google and here but unfortunately  I have not found what I'm looking for.

So my problem is with the following lines :

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract PsoukraceFactory {

```
struct Psoukrace {

    string name;
    string title;
    uint level;

    uint HP;
    uint defence;
    uint dodge;
    uint luck;
    uint intelligence;
    uint strenghth;
    uint attack;
    uint speed;

}

Psoukrace [] public psoukraces;


function _createPsoukrace( string memory name, string memory title, uint  level, uint HP, uint defence, uint dodge, uint luck, uint intelligence, uint strength, uint attack, uint speed) public view returns (string memory, uint) {
   psoukraces.push(Psoukrace(name, title, level, HP, defence, dodge, luck, intelligence, strength, attack, speed));
   return ("test1",
   "test2",
   1,
   2,
   3,
   4,
   5,
   6,
   7,
   8,
   9);
  
}
```

}

I get the following error :

Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
--> contracts/Psoukrace.sol:27:8:

I don't understand what happened as I have seen (maybe I'm wrong here) I have 11 variables as arguments ( 2 string + 9 uint ) same into my psoukraces array and into my Psoukrace struct

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this `return` statement

```
     returns (string memory, uint)
```

this saying you are going to return 2 things: string and uint. However, in function, you are returning

```
return ("test1",
   "test2",
   1,
   2,
   3,
   4,
   5,
   6,
   7,
   8,
   9);
```

11 elements. you have to add each type into `returns()`.

```
 returns (string memory,string memory,uint,uint...9times)
```

after you fixed this you will get another error saying that "Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable". Becase your marked your function as `view` which means that your function is not going to modify the state but you are actually modifying by pushing `psoukraces.push()`. so you also have to remove the `view` from the function.